# sharepoint search using rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2010

I am doing the search in Sharepoint 2013 using rest Api. Everything is working fine. When I enter the search term in search text box, it crawls through the whole content of site and shows all the pages in result that contain search term. Is it possible to crawl through only the part of the pages(e.g only body content, leaving header and footer) and through the page names only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Just put the class "noindex" on the element that you don't want to appear in the search result. In my case, I put the class "noindex" on my divs containing the header, footer and menuholder.